# How do I manually make a .pack file like TexturePacker (without using TexturePacker)?

Tags: libgdx, textures, texture-atlas

I am using libGDX and apparently the only way I see for creating a UI is with texture packs.

I would say that since a texture pack is nothing more than JSON or XML file and a large png I could manually code a texture pack. How?

Comment: What would be the benefit of doing it manually?
Or, maybe better phrased, what is the disadvantage of getting the tool to generate this for you?

Comment: Of course it's possible.  Here's the source: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/extensions/gdx-tools/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tools/texturepacker ; reverse engineer it to your heart's content.  You probably won't find a step-by-step guide to do so, though.

Comment: @bornander The disadvantage is the $40 price tag. I need some of the features in the "pro version" but will not be able to afford until next month. I am always tight on money an this is an exceptionally bad month for me. I only started wanting to implements buttons after I finished my core game and now I need a menu, stats and other screens like that that will use a stage and ui toole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend you creating texture atlas manually. With only two textures it looks like this:

```
atlas.png
size: 1024,256
format: RGBA8888
filter: Linear,Linear
repeat: none
player
  rotate: false
  xy: 404, 4
  size: 400, 174
  orig: 400, 174
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
tank
  rotate: false
  xy: 2, 2
  size: 400, 176
  orig: 400, 176
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

What is your problem with automatic atlas creating? You can either use TexturePacker GUI or run TexturePacker from code which is cool because you don't need manually edit anything after adding new texture.

Comment: My problem is the only TexturePacker I know of has a $40 price tag after a 7 day trial. I would like to mention that I am probably the cheapest person in the world.

Comment: No! Everything that comes with libGDX is completely free. This is how to use it from code https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer .  And this is GUI https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-texturepacker-gui/ . You probably went accidentally here https://www.codeandweb.com/store/texturepacker-single .

Comment: I'm glad to help you.